# Cloudfront Multiple origins within the same bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, cdn

I have a cloudfront distribution which I'm using with a single S3 bucket as the origin. The bucket has both private and public data in it, segregated by folders - `public_folder_1, public_folder_2, private_folder_1, private_folder_2`. I want to use cloudfront to serve only the content from the 2 public folders. I want requests to `xxx.cloudfront.net/public_folder_1/file1` to go to `public_folder_1` and requests to `xxx.cloudfront.net/public_folder_2/file1` to go to `public_folder_2`.

I have created 2 origins within the distro with origin name + paths - `mybucket/public_folder_1` and `mybucket/public_folder_2` for the 2 folders. I have also created two behaviours with path patterns - `public_folder_1/*` and `public_folder_2/*` (I have tried adding a leading `/` to the path pattern, it doesn't seem to make a difference) . But I can't access files via cloudfront.

If I change the path pattern for either behaviour to `*` instead of `public_folder_x/*` then I can access files using `xxx.cloudfront.net/filex` . My concern with this is that if I have 2 files with the same name in both folders how would cloudfront know which folder to use as the origin? I don't want to have to create and manage a seperate distro for each origin path.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm facing a very similar dilemma.

Comment: Nope. I guess that the only way out is to create a seperate distro for each public folder

Answer (score 9):

In my case, I wasn't understanding that when CloudFront finds a matching behavior, it forwards *the entire URL path to S3*. If a matching directory structure isn't represented in your S3 bucket subdirectory, you'll get a 403 response. For example, if you have a behavior matching on `/developer/*`, and the url is `{hostname}/developer/thing.html`, the S3 bucket directory which represents your origin *must* have a root-level subdirectory named "developer" that contains `thing.html`.

> My concern with this is that if I have 2 files with the same name in both folders how would cloudfront know which folder to use as the origin?

You'd have to find some way to distinguish the files by a matching pattern. I would suggest adding uniquely named folders to each origin, then creating behaviors to divert traffic based on the path provided:

- origin1: `mybucket/stuff`
- origin2: `mybucket/things`
- behavior1: `/stuff/*` --> origin1
- behavior2: `/things/*` --> origin2
- `cloudfront-url/stuff/file.html` --> returns `file.html` in the stuff directory, aka origin1.
- `cloudfront-url/things/file.html` --> returns `file.html` in the things directory, aka origin2.

---

## Edit:

I just created a single distro with the following two origins...

[image: origins]

With the following behaviors...

[image: behaviors]

And the following bucket structure...

[image: S3]

And here are the results:

- https://d103l0p0xb29zj.cloudfront.net/file.html > matches default behavior, so returns `file.html` from `S3-stackoverflow-test-bucket/public_folder_1`.
- https://d103l0p0xb29zj.cloudfront.net/pub1/file.html > matches first behavior, returns `file.html` from `S3-stackoverflow-test-bucket/public_folder_1/pub1`
- https://d103l0p0xb29zj.cloudfront.net/pub2/file.html > matches second behavior, returns `file.html` from `S3-stackoverflow-test-bucket/public_folder_2/pub2`
- Note that `S3-stackoverflow-test-bucket/public_folder_2/file.html` is *not* accessible at all based on the current rules.

I'll leave the distro up for a few days so you can click the links.

Comment: Hey Nick, that's exactly what my question is about. I did set up two paths (in my root dir) with 2 behaviours - "I have created 2 origins within the distro with origin name + paths - mybucket/public_folder_1 and mybucket/public_folder_2 for the 2 folders. I have also created two behaviours with path patterns - public_folder_1/* and public_folder_2/* ". It doesn't work. Cloudfront just ends up caching a single directory

Comment: I don't think that's exactly correct. In that example, `public_folder_1` and `public_folder2` are *origins*. Each origin is equivalent of a URL of `hostname/`. You need a distinguishing subdirectory in each origin and then create behaviors that match the subdirectory names in order for it to work. Put another way, in your example, you cannot match on the names `public_folder_1` and `public_folder2`. Stand by, I will update my answer for clarity.

Comment: Thank you for this comment. The first paragraph just solve all my problems. If I could I would buy you a beer.

Comment: This works great. Thanks alot, Nick! Here's a !